# OpenGLES 1.x Toon shading

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to get some toon shadding like effect for primitive types, ie. rectangles or triangles. for now I first render my vertices using GL_LINE_LOOP with GL_TEXTURE_2D disabled and then using GL_TRIANGLES with GL_TEXTURE_2D enabled. the effect is as follows.

[image: http://oi43.tinypic.com/o03ssl.jpg]

My questions are, 1. how can I get rid of the lines between the blocks and 2. how can I make the lines black without affecting everything else beeing rendered afterwards?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For #1, two options

1. rendering **all** lines before drawing any triangles (currently looks like you draw lines then triangles for each object individually).
2. use the depth buffer to place your lines behind the triangles you are drawing.

For question #2, can you elaborate what you mean? Why would changing the line color to black affect anything else being rendered?

Comment: when i use glColor4f evverything will be in that color. when i set 0,0,0,1 the whole screen is black, when i set 1,0,0,1 everything has a red touch

Comment: Just set it to (0,0,0,1), draw the lines, then set it back to (1,1,1,1) after drawing the lines. OpenGL is a state machine, if you change the state (i.e. color) to draw an object, you just have to change it back when you're done drawing that object.